# Number of itels to load in Ionic 3 InfiniteScroll

Tags: ionic3, infinite-scroll

My project is in ionic 3 and I want to use InfiniteScroll on a page which populates list items. In the ionic example for InfiniteScroll they are loading 30 items.
Now different devices have different screen heights. How do I determine the number of items to be loaded every time so that it overflows the page a little bit and make it scrollable?
Is there way I can check if my page has scroll so that I stope loading data.